# How do I correctly bind a string in my model to an TextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm getting the binding errors, e.g.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyText' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-401799582)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyText; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-401799582); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

When trying to bind a string property of my model to a TextBox and a TextBlock (the error above is the one for the TextBox).

I've tried loosely following the [how-to in Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-control-when-the-textbox-text-updates-the-source?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

in xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <src:MyView x:Key="myView"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>Input:</Label>
            <TextBox>
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Source="StaticResource myView" Path="MyText" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <Label>In model:</Label>
                <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Source="StaticResource myView" Path="MyText"/>
                </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

in C#:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MyView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyView() { }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _myText;
        public string MyText
        {
            set
            {
                if (_myText != value)
                {
                    _myText = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyText"));
                }
            }
            get { return _myText;  }
        }

    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the TextBlock to display my text as I type it in the TextBox, but it runs and nothing happens (which makes sense seeing as there was a binding error).

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing StaticResource in a string doesn't mean that you referenced that resource. StaticResource is a markup extension and has its own syntax (curly braces):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Input:</Label>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource myView}" Path="MyText" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

    <Label>In model:</Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource myView}" Path="MyText"/>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

you can also write the same markup in significantly less verbose way:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Input:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Source={StaticResource myView}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Label>In model:</Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Source={StaticResource myView}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

or even better - declare DataContext, not a Resource:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <src:MyView />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>Input:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    
            <Label>In model:</Label>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```